# jquery array push to php foreach

Tags: php, jquery, html, arrays

I'm getting this error in php:

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

I am tring to create an array in jquery for the input values

```
<input type="text" class="passenger">
<input type="text" class="passenger">
<input type="text" class="passenger">
```

Then the js is :

```
var passengers = new Array();

$('.passenger').each(function(){
    if($(this).val() == " "){
        passengers.push(JSON.stringify($(this).val()));
    }
});
```

Then after i post it to php, i am wanting it so i displays all the passengers

at the moment, this is not working. Why not

```
foreach($passengers as $pass){
    $each_passengers = json_decode($pass);
}
```

Comment: `$passengers` is not a array but a string. You are doing a `.stringify` which convert the json data to a string.

Comment: You can use `passengers.push($(this).val());` and `var data = JSON.stringify(passengers)` before data sending and then something like `$passengers = json_decode($data)` in PHP.

Comment: `if($(this).val() == " "){` will just add empty values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you don't need to stringify each input. What you need to do first, is create a grouping name attribute in your form inputs:

```
<input type="text" name="input[]" class="passenger" value="test1" />
<input type="text" name="input[]" class="passenger" value="test2" />
<input type="text" name="input[]" class="passenger" value="test3" />
```

Then, in your `$.post()`. Just feed them as serialized using `$(form).serialize()`:

```
$.post('myphp_process.php', $('#form_values').serialize(), function(response){
```

Then of course the PHP that will process it, just treat it as normal POST:

```
$inputs = $_POST['input']; // this will return an array of inputs and to access this you need a loop.

// for clarity print_r($_POST['input']);
```

[Check this out.](http://codepad.viper-7.com/RJbwFE) This should give you the basic idea.